# Expression to "lookup" value of a field in another layer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I am mapping out the electrical grid infrastructure of my country. I have a **Substations** layer (with *fid* and *name* fields) and a **Existing_Lines** layer (with *fid*, *substation_start*, *substation_end* and *label* layers.

[image: Screenshot of geometries]

*substation_start* and *substation_end* represent the nodes to which the power line connects, so the example in the attached image shows the power line starting at  "Botesland" substation and ending at "Welterede" substation. Both fields are related to the **Substations** layer as shown below (rows 11 and 12).

[image: Screenshot of relations in project properties]

I want to include the field *label* as a label to display on the map next to the power lines showing the route of the power line. The label of the example should display "Botesland - Weltevrede" but when I use the expression `concat("substation_start", " - ", "substation_end")` in the calculator for the *label* field in the **Existing_Lines** layer, QGIS returns the string `1 - 2` as a value in the field.

I understand why it's doing this - the fields *substation_start* and *substation_end* contain integers with the *fid* value of the features it references in the **Substations** layer...

Therefore, I need an expression that will "Lookup" the value in the *name* field for the *fid* of the feature on the other layer...

Can anyone please help me find the right expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a feature from another layer in an expression, and then query a particular attribute of that feature.

The feature is retrieved with the `get_feature` function like so:

```
get_feature( layer,  field,  field_value_to_match)
```

The attribute of interest is queried by passing the feature to the `attribute` function.

```
attribute(get_feature( layer,  field,  field_value_to_match), attribute_of_interest)
```

The following expression is used on the `Existing lines` layer.

```sql
concat(
    attribute(get_feature('substations', 'fid', "substation_start"), 'name'),
    '-',
    attribute(get_feature('substations', 'fid', "substation_end"), 'name')
)
```

Here I get the feature from `substations` where its `fid` is equal to the value in the `substation_start` field of the *`Existing_lines`* layer. Then I get the attribute value of the `name` field from that feature. Likewise with `substation_end`, and then `concat` them, with which you are already familiar.

Be careful with single and double quotes. `"substation_start"` in double quotes signifies the attribute *value* in the current layer (`Existing lines`). The single quotes around the other field names are required for the functions to work. You are passing the *field name* as an argument, rather than the attribute value.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!!!! Thanks